# startActivity by javascriptinterface

Tags: android

Activity does not start...

**MainActivity.java:**

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            WebView web;

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                web = new WebView(this);
                setContentView(web);
                WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
                settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
                web.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
                settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
                web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/simple.html");

            }

            public class JavaScriptInterface {
                Context mContext;

                /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
                JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
                    mContext = c;
                }

                public void order() {
                    Log.d("JS", "StartActivity");
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Order.class));

                }
            }
        }
```

**javascript.js:**

```
function order() {
   Android.order();
}
```

**My simple.html:**

```
   <html>
       <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Simple</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
       </head>

    <body>
       <div class="product">
          <img src="images/p1.png" width="130" height="200">
          <input class="submit-button" onclick="order()" type="button" value="Submit" />
       </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**startActivity:**

```
   public class Order extends Activity{
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          }

      }
```

When i click button, logcat show:

```
04-19 21:46:42.790: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(24323): blockWebkitDraw
04-19 21:46:42.790: V/WebViewInputDispatcher(24323): blockWebkitDraw lockedtrue
04-19 21:46:42.790: V/webview(24323):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -  getEditableSupport  FASLE 
04-19 21:46:43.280: D/webview(24323): blockWebkitViewMessage= false
```

I read a lot of information about this topic, but for some reason it does not work. Please help solve this problem.

Comment: hello, yes could you please post your javascript which I presume is invoking your function and hence startActivity?

Comment: "I tried it all" is not a good description of everything you did. It is also very undescriptive of what happened when you did it. What is the problem, what errors do you get, etc, etc...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP tried everything. Logically, this means that there is no answer possible that OP didn't try, and therefore no answer that will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a javascript interface you have to annotate the methods you want to use in javascript with `@JavascriptInterface` like this:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void order() {
        Log.d("JS", "StartActivity");
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Order.class));
    }
}
```

You should also look in the logcat for any errors, the javascript errors that for example the order function could not be found should show up there as well.

Comment: Well then look at the logcat, there must be some other error too.

Comment: public void order() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

This is working... But startActivity does not.......

Comment: You mean the toast is shown, but the `Activity` is not started?

Comment: This also solved my issue . Thanks a lot @XaverKapeller